# Make shortcut in start menu with innosetup

Tags: windows, winapi, installation, inno-setup

I made an installer using the ISTool wizard and everything is fine. Under my program name in the start menu, I have

MyApp
MyApp Help

Now, I want to add 2 more entries that are identical to the first (MyApp) but that passes a command line argument to the executable

MyApp
MyApp (Console Mode)
MyApp (Remote Admin Mode)
MyApp Help

Should I make batch files and add them (how do I assign an icon to a .bat) or is there some sort of built in system to do this in inno?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add more shortcut entries

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp (Console Mode)"; Filename: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE"; Parameters: "/console"
```